# Generating an array of dates in python

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I am writing a python script that produces a bar graph of data between two dates specified by the user

For example here the user enters 30 November and 4 December

import datetime as dt
dateBegin = dt.date(2012,11,30)
dateEnd = dt.date(2012,12,4)

Is there a way to return an array of the dates between dateBegin and dateEnd?
What I want is something like [30, 1, 2, 3, 4]. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! You are looking for [matplotlib.dates.drange](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.drange):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import datetime as DT

dates = mdates.num2date(mdates.drange(DT.datetime(2012, 11, 30),
                                      DT.datetime(2012, 12, 4),
                                      DT.timedelta(days=1)))
print(dates)
# [datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 30, 0, 0, tzinfo=<matplotlib.dates._UTC object at 0x8c8f8ec>), datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<matplotlib.dates._UTC object at 0x8c8f8ec>), datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 2, 0, 0, tzinfo=<matplotlib.dates._UTC object at 0x8c8f8ec>), datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo=<matplotlib.dates._UTC object at 0x8c8f8ec>)]

vals = np.random.randint(10, size=len(dates))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(dates, vals, align='center')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.xticks(rotation=25)
ax.set_xticks(dates)
plt.show()
```

[image]